# failed to load resource error: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)

Tags: html, r

I'm trying to create a plot with my data from a script given to me by my professor in Rstudio using the cluster package. I'm not the best with R, she wasn't available to help me fix it.
This is the error I got when I inspected a blank plot graph that came back blank:

[image]

[image]

different plot graph from the same data using the same function:

[image]

I was expecting my graph to come back filled, as everything else I have done has worked in Rstudio so far. I've restarted the program and redid my work in new files, I've restarted and updated my computer and the programs necessary, I emailed my professor for help (she wasn't available). I'm not quite sure what my issue is. I got the same results every time - blank plot graph. I am not sure if I need to download a different or new package or if the script is incorrect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.